# Button click on dojo not working

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi friends I am new to "DOJO". I tried to create a button and onclick event I want it to call a function, my code as follows

```
<input id="execute" type="button" value="Get Details">
require([
      "dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
                dom,on
    ) {

on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute); 

            function execute () { alert("here");}
 });
```

But the function execute is not calling. I tried a lot, but not working. Please help me guys.

Comment: I got TypeError: dom.byId is not a function in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself works fine as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7bwK/

But I'm noticing that you're not putting `<script>` tags around your code, is that just because you copy pasted it here, or did you really forget them? Your code should (at least) be something like:

```html
<input id="execute" type="button" value="Get Details">
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
      "dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      dom,on
    ) {
        function execute () { alert("here");}
        on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute); 
    });
</script>
```

If you just didn't copy these, then verify if Dojo is loaded or not. Also, try and see if moving the `execute()` function above the `on()` function solves the problem.

---

If these solutions do not solve your problem, open your browser console (usually <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and see if any error occurs.

Comment: But you can see it works fine on the fiddle, can't you? Can you open your browser console and see what it says?

Comment: Yah but im working on ARCGIS javascript API. It uses dojo. check this https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_nomap.html

Comment: I got TypeError: dom.byId is not a function

Comment: @Aisha Then I'm pretty sure you didn't give us the entire `require()` block. Check that the `dojo/dom` module is correctly mapped onto the `dom` variable.